# Merge Multiple Text File & Create One file

Tags: batch-file

Some background:

- I am completely new to Batch Scripting
- I am trying to batch merge multiple TEXT files in a single folder without having the header/Footer duplicated.
- The text files are in the folder and names of text files changes, so what ever text files are in the folder will be merged.
- The Master file generated from this merged file will have the HEADER.
- The Master file will be saved on today's date and Q as name.(010913Q)

  ```
  data1.text:
  XYZ Company's Name Date:31082013
  Sam81211..............
  John71511..............
  Bob61511..............
  Total ................................

  data2.text:
  XYZ Company's Name Date:31082013
  Billy71410..............
  Sara9811..............
  Joey6210..............
  Total ................................

  data3.text:
  XYZ Company's Name Date:31082013
  Hank3509..............
  Sally42811..............
  Gina1211..............
  Total ................................

  Master File.Text
  XYZ Company's Name Date:31082013    <--- HEADER
  Sam81211
  John71511
  Bob61511
  Billy71410
  Sara9811
  Joey6210
  Hank3509
  Sally42811
  Gina1211

  SAVED AS 010913Q in the same folder.
  ```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
copy data1.text 010913Q
<data2.text>>010913Q more +1
<data3.text>>010913Q more +1
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses Endoro's ideas.

**EDIT**  I added a line that shows the order of file processing and corrected the final filename.

It works here and provides this:

```
XYZ Company's Name Date:31082013
Sam81211..............
John71511..............
Bob61511..............
Billy71410..............
Sara9811..............
Joey6210..............
Hank3509..............
Sally42811..............
Gina1211..............
```

This is substantially the same code - your filenames are sorted by alpha characters and need to be in a sortable format as that will determine which file is processed first, second etc.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set name=tmp.tmp
set "flag="
for %%a in (*.text) do (
echo processing "%%a"
   if not defined flag (
     copy "%%a" "%name%" >nul
     set flag=1
    ) else (
     more +1 "%%a" >>"%name%"
   )
)
findstr /v "^Total" < "%name%" >"%mm%%dd%%yyyy:~2%Q"
del "%name%"
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive, Please help to remove the footer line it is not required. (Total ............)

Comment: The last two lines above should remove the footers.

Comment: Sorry Foxidrive, after test run i have found that from file 2 (data2.text:) the line after header also gets delete in above case its (Billy71410..............) & else every thing is perfect, Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Foxidrive, actually there is no issue of file sorting format.

Comment: Hi Foxidrive, actually there is no issue of file sorting. When ever the 2nd file is merged/appended the line after header is also deleted, It deletes one row extra.  The 3,4 file is appended properly, then why it delete the 2 line from second file and appends. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: I showed you above what it produces with the filenames you gave.  You have some other issue happening.